# Trying to code random response to command

Tags: node.js

*Edit: I thought I was using Discord.js, but it turns out I was using Node.js. Sorry for the confusion.*

I'm very new to coding. Like, less than 24 hrs into it.

I'm trying to make a command for a bot in Discord (for example `!cat` will generate some random responses.) However, every time I try to list multiple responses for the bot to choose from, it doesn't work. The website I used to lay everything out says its fine, but when I type it into discord, nothing happens. I'm using some pre-made coding lines that I've modified for my personal use.

*Below is how I have it laid out...*

```
const lib = require("lib")({ token: process.env.STDLIB_SECRET_TOKEN });

if (context.params.event.content === `'!cat'`) {
  let messageContent = context.params.event.content === `'!cat'`;

  await lib.discord.channels["@0.1.0"].messages.create({
    channel_id: context.params.event.channel_id,
    content: [`message one`, `message two`, `message three`, `message four`][
      Math.floor(Math.random() * messages.length)
    ],
  });
}
```

Comment: What is `lib`, `context`, `messages`? My assumption without knowing those members is that *`'!cat'`* is supposed to be just *`!cat`*. Otherwise you would actually have to enter *'!cat'* into Discord. In general your code doesn't look very discord.js-like at all.

Comment: I went ahead and edited my tags, but I realized I was actually using node.js instead of discord. Sorry for the confusion. I'm still new at this.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code that works in discord.js

```js
let content = [`message one`, `message two`, `message three`, `message four`]
if (message.content.includes("!test")) {
    message.channel.send(content[Math.floor(Math.random() * content.length)])
}
```

But you used `lib` and got `context` and `messages` out of nowhere.
If you are coding with discord.js tho, this works perfectly for me.

As you can see here, the code works:

```js
let content = [`message one`, `message two`, `message three`, `message four`]
console.log(content[Math.floor(Math.random() * content.length)])
```

Comment: I made a mistake and realized that I was using Node.js instead of Discord.js. I went ahead and edited my tags. Sorry for the confusion, I'm still really new to this.